# Create a Digital Diary for, each member, in Microsoft Teams

Tags: microsoft-teams

Is there a way to create something similar to a Microsoft Diary for each member at Microsoft Teams?
Where each member recorded what they do each day, put files, etc.

Thanks.

Comment: did you try onenote?, like add a onenote app to your team and let each member have a notebook for themselves.

Comment: OneDrive is also an option, or a combo of OneNote (notes) + OneDrive (files)

Comment: Thank You :)!
I will try this!